# How can I sum dates in excel using python in a function

Tags: python, xlwings

I have a function that should return the sum of two cells with date format. However in a function keeps giving me datetime.datetime error.

I tried a direct link to the cell value and do print(day1-day2) and works but does not work under the return. result = day1-day2 return result

```
for cell in rng:
    if cell.value and value1 and value3 in cell.value:
        if cell.offset(0,2).value == well:
            day2 = sheet.range('c' + str(cell.row)).options(dates=dt.datetime).value

return day2 - day1
```

This works if I am not using it under a function:

import xlwings as xw
    wb = xw.books.active
    sheet = wb.sheets[2]

```
Lastrow = wb.sheets[2].range('D' + str(wb.sheets[2].cells.last_cell.row)).end('up').row


day = sheet.range('c2').value
day2 = sheet.range('c3').value

print(day2-day)

>> 16:58:54
```

Comment: What `datetime` error is it giving you specifically?

Comment: @Axium the error I am getting is: TypeError: Objects of type 'datetime.timedelta' cannot be converted to a COM VARIANT.

Comment: try: return str(day2 - day1)

Comment: @AnnaNevison incredible, never came to my mind that could've been the issue. Thanks for your help.

Comment: was that the answer? if so i'll put it in the answer section so you can close this